# java replacing elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

The main question will be at the bottom. From the text file below, lets say the first integer is a, second is b, and third is c and so forth. the program takes a,b and c, parses them, puts them into myCalculations method which returns a string with two integers. The string is parsed, a and b are replaced the integers in said returned string, then the next iteration of the loop will take the new values for a and b, and integer d. This will continue until the end where a and b are printed to the user.

The input from a two text files is as follows:

The format of the text file is as follows:

```
200 345 
36
45
36
21
```

Here is the reading in from the file, it works as intended, I put it here for context. tl;dr is results[] is an integer array for the first line. (int a and b)

```
public class conflictTrial
{
    BufferedReader in;
    public static void conflictTrial() throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        System.out.print('\u000c');
        System.out.println("please enter the name of the text file you wish you import. Choose either costs.txt or lotsacosts.txt Nothing else");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
        File file = new File(filename);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String element1 = null;
        try {
            element1 = in.readLine();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            //  handle exception
        }

        String[] firstLine = element1.split(" ");

        Arrays.stream(firstLine).forEach(fl -> {
            //System.out.println("First line element: \t\t\t" + fl);
        });

        int[] results = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < firstLine.length; i++) 
        {
            try {
                int stuff = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[i]);
                results[i] = stuff;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                // handle error   
            }
        }
```

The bufferreader reads in the file, the for loop parses the integers into array results[]. Next, the remaining lines are parsed and method myCalculations is called:

```
 String otherElement = null;
 int[] aliveSoldiers = new int[100];
 int [] things = new int [100];
 int[] newResults = new int[100];
 try {
      while ((otherElement = in.readLine()) != null) {       // main loop
          System.out.println("Line to process:\t\t\t" + otherElement);
          String[] arr = otherElement.split(" ");

          for (int k = 0; k <arr.length; k++) 
          {
              int thingsResult = Integer.parseInt(arr[k]);
              things[k] = thingsResult;
              System.out.println("number of days: \t\t\t"+things[k]);

              aliveSoldiers[0] = results[0];
              aliveSoldiers[1] = results[1];
              String returnAliveSoliders = myCalculations(aliveSoldiers[0], aliveSoldiers[1], things[k]);
              System.out.println("return soldiers alive: \t\t"+returnAliveSoliders);

              String[] newItems = returnAliveSoliders.split(" ");


              for (int f = 0; f < newItems.length; f++) 
              {
                  int newParse = Integer.parseInt(newItems[f]);
                  newResults[f] = newParse;
                  aliveSoldiers[0] = newResults[0];
                  aliveSoldiers[1] = newResults[1];
              } 
              k++;
          }
       } 
   }
    catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Currently the code does the following: first of the main loop iteration takes integer a, b and c, second iteration takes the same integers a and b (200 and 345, the initial values) with integer d, the third iteration takes the same values for and a and b with integer e. I have attempted to address this issue with the following code:

```
aliveSoldiers[0] = newResults[0];
aliveSoldiers[1] = newResults[1];
```

I need to take the integers from the method myCalculations (parsed in the k-modifier loop), and overwrite them into aliveSoldiers[0] and aliveSoldiers [1] so the program reads the next line, takes the new integers, and continues until there are no more days remaining.

Comment: You update `newResult[f]` but always use `newResult[0]` and `newResult[1]` in the next line. Could you try to summarize the need. See what is a [mcve] including examples.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly haven't understood what the whole exercise should do, but the code You enlighted could be wrong due to the indexes You use: those indexes are always 0 and 1, even if cycles are performed through some other indexes. At the end of the second code snippet, the f-for modify the array "newResults" at the increasing index "f", but that array is read always at the same index: 0 and then 1. So, if "f" gets higher values than "1" then the "aliveSoldiers"'s elements are left unchanged.

In particular, aliveSoldiers is modified only on the first two indexes, the other indexes are not used at all.

Do you need a stack-like or queue-like behaviour?

Comment: this is completely not the case, but I think it makes sense: lets say a and b are soldiers and catapults, c is the number of days of a battle. The death toll on a and b is a function of the number of days the battle lasts. after myCalculations is called, it returns the remaining soldiers, reads the next integer (d) and computes the soldiers remaining after the second battle. I have no idea what I need, not even sure what is wrong.

Comment: Is there a problem with replacing elements of this array like this at the end of the  f-for modifier? also, with array[100] i just chose a big number so it wouldn't max out.

Comment: In this case i advise you to use single variables. If you need to keep track of the remaining soldiers on each iteration, then use 2 arrays ("soldiers" for "a" and "catapults" for "b") and use the index of the cycle., that is k or a counter that counts how many days have been passed (how many line have been red). If no track is needed, then use 2 int instead.